# Routing Error No route matches [PATCH] "/locations"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a route error after trying to update a location item

I'm using before_action to set location id

```
before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

private
def set_location
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end
```

here is my controller 
I only have trouble with update new and delete work fine

```
def create
@location = Location.new(location_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @location.save
    format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @location }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @location.update(location_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

here is how my routs are defined

```
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
static_pages_home_path   GET     /static_pages/home(.:format)    static_pages#home
static_pages_help_path   GET     /static_pages/help(.:format)    static_pages#help
static_pages_about_path  GET     /static_pages/about(.:format)   static_pages#abo ut
root_path                    GET     /   static_pages#home  
locations_path           GET     /locations(.:format)    locations#index
                             POST    /locations(.:format)    locations#create
new_location_path            GET     /locations/new(.:format)    locations#new
 edit_location_path          GET     /locations/:id/edit(.:format)   locations#edit
location_path             GET    /locations/:id(.:format)    locations#show
                             PATCH   /locations/:id(.:format)    locations#update
                             PUT     /locations/:id(.:format)    locations#update
                             DELETE  /locations/:id(.:format)    locations#destroy
```

not sure if i need to add anything else

I guess i can add the trace

```
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/johnk/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/johnk/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/johnk/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

_form file

```
<%= form_for @location,:url => locations_path, :html => { :multipart => true , :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :latitude, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :latitude, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :longitude, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :longitude, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :address, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :address, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :user_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :user_id, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :rating, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :rating, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :no_rates, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :no_rates, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

   <%= f.file_field :picture %>



  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil , :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                locations_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

Comment: In your route definition you've `PATCH   /locations/:id` but you're trying to access `/locations`. Your url must be `PATCH /locations/SOME_ID`

Comment: How looks the form ? Do you have a complete stacktrace to show ?

Comment: @HungryCoder I use the same code for creat which seems to work fine.   After saving the view goes to /locations/id

Comment: Could you please also show the template file? I suspect there is something wrong with your template file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You specified a target URL for your form tag instead of letting Rails pick one for you. Because of that, instead of making a PATCH request to `/locations/:id` your form is trying to make one to the URL you specified, which does not have a PATCH route attached to it.

Simply remove the `:url` option from your form tag, like so:

```
<%= form_for @location, :html => { :multipart => true , :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Much nicer than editing routes.